# Bootstrap grid with php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, omeka

I'm making a theme for my Omeka site in which I am calling an item and its various components using PHP. Each item is in its own div, and I have attempted to create a tile-like grid with Bootstrap. However, the divs only line up in a single vertical column. How do I make all divs line up in a row of three or four? I'm completely stumped. It works fine without the PHP (with multiple rows and manually added content) but won't work otherwise. [This is what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYgCM.png). And this is what I want the divs to look like:

[image]

Here is the html/php:

```
  <?php foreach (loop('items') as $item): ?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- attempt at square grid -->
                             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 item-item">
                                 <div class="dummy"></div>
                                     <div class="thumbnail purple">
                                 Image:  <?php $image = $item->Files; ?>
                                <?php if ($image) {
                                        echo link_to_item('<div style="background-image: url(' . file_display_url($image[0], 'original') . ');" class="img"></div>');
                                    } else {
                                        echo link_to_item('<div style="background-image: url(' . img('defaultImage@2x.jpg') . ');" class="img"></div>');
                                    }
                                ?>
                                   Title: <?php echo link_to_item(metadata('item', array('Dublin Core', 'Title')), array('class'=>'permalink')); ?><br>
                                    Creator: <?php echo metadata('item', array('Dublin Core', 'Creator')); ?><br>
                                    Subject: <?php echo metadata('item', array('Dublin Core', 'Subject')); ?><br>
                                    Description: <?php echo metadata('item', array('Dublin Core', 'Description'), array('snippet'=>150)); ?><br>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div><!-- end grid -->
```

And the CSS:

```
.dummy {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:calc(50% - 30px);
}

.item-item { 
    border: solid black 5px;
}
```

Comment: can you add fiddle for us? https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi @Mystika---sure. Here it is: [https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/qx9smztm/](https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/qx9smztm/). Though, I'm not sure if I've added it correctly. Please let me know if I need to upload more code.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a pseudo method of achieving this, harnessing [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk).

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 4);
foreach($chunks as $group): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($group as $element): ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 item-item">
                <?php // do your php stuff...?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#YLVKFapv5)

Comment: Thanks, Darren! So, I've tried this but it has hidden all of the divs---i.e., when I refreshed only the header and footer content were visible. Do you have an idea of what I could've done wrong?

Comment: You'll need to include the other classes as you need, so throw in the `.item`/etc inside the `col-md-3...` divs.

Comment: hm.... still not working. I've added a fiddle here if that helps---[https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/qx9smztm/](https://jsfiddle.net/hcgriggs/qx9smztm/)